# like body option in php what is used in java?

Tags: java, php, json, post, put

The body option is used to control the body of an entity enclosing request (e.g., PUT, POST, PATCH). in PHP it is used like this

```
$client->request('POST', '/post', ['body' => $stream]);
```

But I want to use in java like http://crawler.ankiti.com having json

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "url": "http:\/\/crawler.ankiti.com\/?module=server&do=test",
      "method": "post",
      "options": {
        "body": "post body test 1"
      },
      "target": "wo"
    },
    {
      "url": "http:\/\/crawler.ankiti.com\/?module=server&do=test",
      "method": "post",
      "target": "wo",
      "options": {
        "body": "post body test 1",
        "form_params": {
          "name": "abhay",
          "surname": "aggarwal"
        },
        "headers": {
          "login": "abhay",
          "password": "patparganj405"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "url": "http:\/\/crawler.ankiti.com\/?module=server&do=test",
      "method": "post",
      "target": "wo",
      "options": {
        "multipart": [
          {
            "name": "file text",
            "path": "\/test\/file.txt"
          },
          {
            "name": "file image",
            "path": "\/test\/file.jpg"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "errors": "",
  "meta": ""
}
```

I want to post a string in a body request which is present in json of this url.

Comment: My eyeballs popped out of my head when I tried to read this.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow and everybody should have to start from some place .There for referring this link might help you out http://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow

Comment: Manually writing servlets is low-level and error prone. Use something like Spring MVC or Dropwizard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use httpServlet and follow a procedure like this.

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
// Get the printwriter object from response to write the required json object to the output stream      
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
// Assuming your json object is **jsonObject**, perform the following, it will return your json object  
out.print(jsonObject);
out.flush();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks Rahul for the reply but as I know in PHP  option cannot be used with form_params, multipart, or JSON  so in java is possible

Comment: yes as he question being asked I'm talking only  about Java here